# How to use the library on AndroidX?

Tags: android, androidx

I have written a library that supports `AndroidX`.
How can I use this library with migration if I don't want to migrate my project to AndroidX yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many popular libraries that have supported AndroidX say something like "If you wish to use this library now, migrate to AndroidX or use old versions". So I don't think you can use an AndroidX library with an non-AndroidX project.

Support libraries and AndroidX have different package name space. In the future, new changes in the AndroidX libraries won't be available in the support libraries.

Migrate the project to AndroidX or downgrade the library to support library.

**Update**

As mlyko's comment mentioned, jetifier has a reverse mode:

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier#reverse_mode

> In this mode, the utility converts AndroidX APIs to the support library equivalents, instead of the other way around. Reverse mode is useful, for example, if you are developing libraries that use AndroidX APIs, but also need to distribute versions that use the support library.

I haven't tried it but it seems promising.

Comment: Can u give please example of some popular libraries which use `AndroidX` and who write something like that?

Comment: @Morozov https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/releases says "this release is the first release using androidX, stay with older versions for pure appcompat dependencies" or https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: you could try the jetifier-standalone ( https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier ) in reverse mode, to provide build with support libraries. Therefore you'd have 2 releases of the library - androidx and support lib. (I haven't try the solution)

Comment: @mlyko your comment should be an answer, as not everyone reads comments, and you have important info in that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [jetifier-standalone](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) in reverse mode, to provide build with support libraries. Therefore you'd have 2 releases of the library - androidx and support lib.

Comment: Good decision, but not relevant for me, mb for somebody else ;)